# How to change path of references in Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

Is there a place I can change a path for my references in a Visual Studio (Xamarin Android) project?  I am receiving a ton of warnings (similar to below) and the files are there, but somehow the reference contains an extra backslash (before ref folder).

> The referenced component '[Local path]\NETStandardLibrary.2.0.2\build\netstandard2.0\\ref\System.Text.Encoding.dll' could not be found.

Comment: Have you tried setting the "Copy Local" property of the reference to True? The other option is to set manually the path of the DLL, also as a property of the reference.